# change font text using listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

i have a textbox and listbox
listbox show all of the font in the system. Textbox use for enter a string.
i don't know when user click any item in list box then font of the textbox will be changed.
and mycode only use to show all of font in system. i'm newbie

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InstalledFontCollection fonts = new InstalledFontCollection();
        try
        {
            foreach (FontFamily font in fonts.Families)
            {
                FontListBox.Items.Add(font.Name);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your problem and question, so we don't waste our time to guess. Welcome to Stackoverflow :)

Comment: thank you. i have a form include a listbox and text box, i wanna enter a string in textbox and in listbox i wanna show all of system font. when i select a font form listbox . the font of string in textbox will change.

Answer (score 1):

You should use SelectedIndexChanged event to catch when another font selected by user. Later You can find the font by its name and apply to txt.Font.

```
    InstalledFontCollection fonts;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InstalledFontCollection fonts = new InstalledFontCollection();
        try
        {
            foreach (FontFamily font in fonts.Families)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(font.Name);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Font = new Font(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), textBox1.Font.Size);
    }
```

Comment: My bad, sorry. I updated the code, please try again.

Comment: @Akiko Make sure you have subscribed to the  SelectedIndexChanged event.